# Kotlin - How to implement Rail Fence Cipher?

Tags: kotlin, encryption

I am working on [Rail Fence Cipher](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rail-fence-cipher-encryption-decryption/) encryption.

```
fun main(){
    println("Enter the message:")
    var message:String = readLine()!!.toUpperCase()
    println("Enter the key:")
    var key:Int = readLine()!!.toInt()
    var skip:Int = 2*(key-1)
    var j=0
    var encryptedMsg:String=""
    var key1 = key

    while(key1>0){
        for(i in (key-key1)..message.length step  skip){
            if(i<=message.length-1)
                encryptedMsg+=message[i]
        }
        key1-=1
        skip = 2*(key1-1)
    }
    println("Encrypted Message: $encryptedMsg")
}
I am having trouble with the last row.
```

Here I am getting an error: `Step must be positive, was: 0`. Also I know step won't work for the last row. So is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 1):

```
fun main(){
    println("Enter the message:")
    var message:String = readLine()!!.toUpperCase()
    println("Enter the key:")
    var key:Int = readLine()!!.toInt()
    var skip:Int = 2*(key-1)
    var j=0
    var encryptedMsg:String=""
    var key1 = key

    while(key1>0){
        for(i in (key-key1)..message.length step  skip){
            if(i<=message.length-1)
                encryptedMsg+=message[i]
        }
        key1-=1
        skip = 2*(key1-1)
        if(skip==0) skip=2*(key-1)  //This solves the problem
    }
    println("Encrypted Message: $encryptedMsg")
}
```

Still, if anyone has any better suggestions without two loops I'd like to know. Thank You.